# What is the shortcut to change input language when using hardware keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, languages

I have connected a USB windows keyboard to my tablet. However, regular windows input language switching shortcut do not work on android. What is angular keys to change input language?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Space.  (Not an answer because I'm having trouble with this myself on some keyboards/devices)